# Regarding the $E$-field at the location of discrete point

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, singularities

Most textbooks define the $E$-field at the location of $q_{1}$$\\$

[image]

as: $$\textbf{E}=-\frac{q_{2}}{r_{21}^2}\hat{\textbf{r}}$$

which is finite. However, the field is also defined as the force per unit charge that a test charge would feel if it were to be placed somewhere, with all other charges held fixed.

[image]

And so the field at the position of $dq$ is:

$$E=\frac{q_{1}}{r_{13}^2}\hat{\textbf{r}}-\frac{q_{2}}{r_{23}^2}\hat{\textbf{r}}$$

where $r_{13}$ and $r_{23}$ are the distances from $dq$ to $q_{1}$ and $q_{2}$ respectively. Now, if we want to find the field at $q_{1}$ we will need to shrink $r_{13}$ toward zero, but this will make the field infinite.

So the question is, in reality is the field extremely big at $q_{1}$ or is it finite and equals the first value above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just depends on what you are talking about. In the first case you are considering the field at $q_1$ due to just the charge $q_2$. In the second case you are looking at the field at the location of $\text dq$ caused by both $q_1$ and $q_2$. So you are looking at two different things.

Indeed, $\text dq$ will feel an "infinite force" as it is brought closer and closer to $q_1$. And in your first case $q_1$ will feel an "infinite force" as it is brought closer and closer to $q_2$.

Comment: I have just edited my question.

Comment: @Hilbert Ok. My answer still applies.

Comment: @But in the second, if I take $dq$ very close to $q_{1}$ I'll be essentially looking at the field at $q_{1}$.

Comment: @Hilbert Right. The field very close to $q_1$ caused by $q_1$. In the first scenario you are only looking at the field caused by $q_2$. When you write down $E=q_2/r_{12}^2$ you are only considering the field produced by $q_2$

Comment: And in the second case, we're looking at the field caused by $q_{1}$ itself plus the one caused by $q_{2}$, whereas in the first case, as you said, we're only looking at the field generated by $q_{2}$, but in reality there's only one field, so which of these two fields accurately describe what is happening in reality?

Comment: @Hilbert If you want to talk about the entire field caused by the configuration $q_1$ and $q_2$ together, then obviously use the second scenario.

Comment: So basically the textbooks were inaccurate, because the value of the field at $q_{1}$ that they chose to use clearly doesn't reflect the fact that $q_{1}$ is here, that value would be true had we had only $q_{2}$, which is not the case.

Comment: @Hilbert I don't think the text book is inaccurate at all. You are expecting the first scenario to answer a different question than it was intended to answer. Scenario 1 is perfectly fine if, for example, we wanted to know the force $q_1$ would experience due to the electrostatic interaction with $q_2$. Then $F=q_1E=q_1q_2/r_{12}^2$

Comment: Isn't the charge's own field, and "self interaction", taken into account in Quantum Electrodynamics? Doesn't it turn out to be nearly negligible, because the classically computed infinite value is adjusted by Renormalization? I haven't studied these things formally, but I suspect they're relevant here.

Comment: @electronpusher Sure, but that isn't relevant here. We aren't talking about self-interaction here. We are just talking about what is the correct way to describe the electric field.

Comment: "So basically the textbooks were inaccurate, because the value of the field at $q_{1}$ that they chose to use clearly doesn't reflect the fact that $q_{1}$ is here"... But wouldn't including the self-interaction be what reflects the fact that $q_{1}$ is present, when that is the case?

Answer (score -1):

When particles get close to each other their behaviors and forces between them are governed by quantum mechanics and quantum field theory.

the short answer is the force does not become infinite. 
when you try to bring two charges too close to each other, (let's say two electrons) the quantum effects become important and many unusual things happen.
For example it would be impossible to bring two stationary electrons close to each other because you would not exactly know where the electrons are! This is called Heisenberg's uncertainty principle.

The quantum field theory comes to the play if you apply a very huge force and shoot the electrons toward each other hoping that they collide. in this case new particles can be created.

Comment: The interpretation of QM that the electron does not have a definite position is not the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle. The HUP deals with standard deviations of probability distributions.